# Nginx proxy websocket: is it required to close the connection to backend after upgrading to a websocket?

Tags: nginx, websocket

Base on what I could read on nginx site
https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

The exemple they give will close all connections to backend.  This isn't really what we want on a proxy setup, forcing to reopen a connection to backend on each new client.

```
http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }
 
    upstream websocket {
        server 192.168.100.10:8010;
    }
 
    server {
        listen 8020;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

But is it required to close the connection after upgrading to a websocket?

can't we change the map so it maintains the 'keepalive' connection to the backend ? (for all non websocket requests)

```sh
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
#       ''      close;
        ''      '';
    }
```

Being the only user on a test environment it didn't seem to create any issues, but will it be the same in production?

Answer (score 1):

This `map` does not cause websocket connections to close.

What it actually does is check whether the `Upgrade:` request header contains any value. If it does, then it returns `upgrade`, which is then passed upstream as the header `Connection: upgrade`.

It only returns `close` when the `Upgrade:` request header is missing. This should not happen in normal operation, but if it does happen, then you can't reliably (or at all) establish a websocket connection to the browser anyway.

Comment: `It only returns close when the Upgrade: request header is missing.` but then that is what happens on any classic connection (that are not websocket).  Prior to enabling websocket I had a line `proxy_set_header Connection ''` to not let the client 'close' terminate the keepalive with backend.

Comment: @AntonyGibbs You aren't going to send normal connections to your websocket! You should only send websocket connections to your websocket URL. Which means your `location` needs to have the correct path.